# How do I resolve a "Too many levels of symbolic links" error on my Documents folder?

Tags: files, directory

I tried using root and the absolute path, but got the same error. I also tried changing the ownership of the folder manually to my username, which also resulted in a "too many levels of symbolic links" error message.

I did a little digging to see if there were any problems using `find -L ./ -mindepth 15` in my home directory. That gave me this output:

```
find: ‘./Documents’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./Templates’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./Public’: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: Do you have a symbolic link pointing to a parent directory? If so, you can wind up in an endless loop with recursive operations ...

Comment: Please don't  use screenahots of terminal text. Copy and paste the text into the question and format it.